# Работа с коллекциями в jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

В дополнение к предыдущему вопросу. При нажатии на кнопки ADD TO CART, корзина динамически заполняется информацией про товар(`li` кладутся внутрь `ul`, внутрь `li` также кладется ссылка-кнопка для удаления конкретного элемента).

`$(this).parent('.newLi').remove()` работает, т.е. можно при нажатии удалить конкретный элемент. Вот с `var minusDollar = $(this).closest('.newLi').find('.spanDollar').html()` есть проблема, так как при вычитании сумы `$('#price').html((+price - +minusDollar).toFixed(2))` - вычитается сумма не конкретного товара, а всех товаров вместе взятых. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<div id="container1">
    <div id="cart-menu">
        <span id="yc">Your cart</span>
    </div>
    <div id="counts">
        <span id="counter" class="visible-span">0</span><span class="visible-span">ITEMS</span><span class="visible-span">|</span><span class="visible-span">$</span><span id="price" class="visible-span">0</span>
    </div>
    <ul id="ul"></ul>
</div>

<div id="container2">
    <div class="stuff">
        <img src="images/man1.jpg">
        <p>$<span class="dollar">44.85</span></p>
        <p class="title">JACKET</p>
        <input type="button" value="ADD TO CART" class="btn"  />
    </div>
    <div class="stuff">
        <img src="images/man2.jpg">
        <p>$<span class="dollar">62.95</span></p>
        <p class="title">JEANS</p>
        <input type="button" value="ADD TO CART" class="btn" />
    </div>      
</div>
```

*jQuery*

```
    $(function (){
$('.btn').click(function (){
    //arrow at the bottom should be animated every time you press the button
    $(function(){
        $('#arrow').animate(
            {
                bottom: '300px',
                fontSize: '60px',
                opacity: '0'
            }, 2000,(function(){
                $('#arrow')
                    .css('opacity', '1')
                    .css('bottom', '0')
                    .css('fontSize', '0')
            }));
    });

    //+1 to ITEMS every time you press the button
    var counter = $('#counter').html();
    counter++;
    $('#counter').html(counter);

    //add price to the cart
    var dollar = $(this).closest('.stuff').find('.dollar').html();
    var title = $(this).closest('.stuff').find('.title').html();
    var price = $('#price').html();
    $('#price').html((+price + +dollar).toFixed(2));

    //+1 li element to the hidden cart at the top of the site

    var bool = false;

    //creating new elements, that should be contain stuff info *WRITTEN IN JavaScript*
    var ul = document.getElementById('ul');
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.setAttribute('class', 'newLi');
    var spanPrice = document.createElement('span');
    spanPrice.setAttribute('class', 'spanPrice');
    spanPrice.innerHTML = 'Price:';
    var spanDollar = document.createElement('span');
    spanDollar.setAttribute('class', 'spanDollar');
    spanDollar.innerHTML = dollar;
    var spanStuff = document.createElement('span');
    spanStuff.setAttribute('class', 'spanStuff');
    spanStuff.innerHTML = 'Stuff:';
    var spanTitle = document.createElement('span');
    spanTitle.setAttribute('class', 'spanTitle');
    spanTitle.innerHTML = title;
    var del = document.createElement('a');
    del.setAttribute('class', 'del');
    del.setAttribute('href', '#');
    del.innerHTML = 'X';
    var yourCart = document.getElementById('yc');
    yourCart.innerHTML = '';
    var ycLink = document.createElement('a');
    ycLink.setAttribute('id', 'ycLink');
    ycLink.setAttribute('href', '#');
    ycLink.innerHTML = 'Your cart';
    var firstLi = document.createElement('li');
    firstLi.setAttribute('id', 'firstLi');
    var removeCart = document.createElement('input');
    removeCart.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    removeCart.setAttribute('value', 'REMOVE CART');
    removeCart.setAttribute('id', 'removeCart');

    //add elements to the hidden cart *WRITTEN IN JavaScript*
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
    newLi.appendChild(spanPrice);
    newLi.appendChild(spanDollar);
    newLi.appendChild(spanStuff);
    newLi.appendChild(spanTitle);
    newLi.appendChild(del);
    yourCart.appendChild(ycLink);
    firstLi.appendChild(removeCart);

    // open/close hidden cart
    $('#ycLink').click(function(){
       if(!bool){
           bool = true;
           ul.insertBefore(firstLi, ul.firstChild);
           //option to remove all cart elements
           $('#removeCart').click(function (){
               $('li').remove();
               $('#ycLink').remove();
               $('#price').html('0');
               $('#counter').html('0');
               $('#yc').html('Your cart');
               $('#ul').css('display', 'none');
               bool = false;
           });
           $('#ul').slideDown('slow');
       }
        else{
           bool = false;
           $('#ul').slideUp('slow');
           $('#firstLi').remove();
       }
    });

    //remove selected elements
    $('.del').click(function (){
        $(this).parent().remove();
        counter--;
        $('#counter').html(counter);
        var minusDollar = $(this).closest('.newLi').find('.spanDollar').html();
        $('#price').html((+price - +minusDollar).toFixed(2));
        if(ul.lastChild === firstLi){
            $('#firstLi').remove();
            $('#ycLink').remove();
            $('#price').html('0');
            $('#yc').html('Your cart');
            $('#ul').css('display', 'none');
            bool = false;
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: не используйте уже отвеченый вопрос, чтобы спросить что-то еще - задайте новый вопрос.  Очевидно, что Вы сначала удаляете `$(this).parent('.newLi')`, а потом пытаетесь получить из него `minusDollar`.

Comment: Касательно нового вопроса - прийму во внимание. Что касается кода, то я закоментировал $(this).parent()remove(), тем не менее все тоже самое

Comment: Вы не показали код, который выполняется при клике "ADD TO CART". Выражение `$(this).closest('.newLi').find('.spanDollar')`, вероятно, не отражает структуру DOM.

Comment: Задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос. В коде, который Вы добавили, слишком много проблемных мест. То, что Вы делаете с jQuery и динамическими DOM элементами, работать не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dollar = $(this).parent().find('.dollar').html();
```

или

```
var dollar = $(this).closest('.stuff').find('.dollar').html();
```

Comment: в варианте с parent ошибка, верно будет так parent()

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer - спасибо

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.